# reactjs table body isnt loading data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a dynamic loading table where I have the mission to build headings, and body based on a complex nested API, but once I try to render such dummy API I got only the titles, but not the body

```
const arr = [
  {
      "Demo": [
          {
              "id": "T0810",
              "name": "Data Historian Compromise",
              "tags": [
                  "Demo"
              ],
              "queries": [],
              "urls": [],
              "max_leght": [],
              "count_items": []
          },
      ],
    }
  ];


  const modArray = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(i => {
    return {id: i, ...arr[0][i]}
  });
  
  const rowKeys = Object.keys(modArray[0]).filter(i => {
    i !== "id"
  });
  
  export default function Demo() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            {modArray.map(i => <th key={i.id}>{i.id}</th>)}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {rowKeys.map(rowKey => <tr key={rowKey}>
            {modArray.map(item => <td key={item.id}>{item[rowKey]}</td>)}
          </tr>)}
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding exactly what you need to be rendered, I cannot help you.
I created a playground on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-feynman-kob33?file=/src/App.js You can duplicate and modify it

Can you explain (e.g. using static data) what output in the DOM you are expecting exactly?

Comment: I am trying to render Demo array of objects where "Demo" is one of the 11 categories where each category contains child objs with more data , but I want to render each child obj into each category

Comment: @anaosuna, if you could provide a codesandbox with the layout you want, it would be helpful. If in the meantime you found the solution, please share it here answering your own question :)